# Dynamically Typed list

Tags: c#, .net

I am wondering if this is possible, what I want to do is set the type of list when I create an instance of this class.

```
class MyClass
{
    private Type _type = typeof(string);
    public MyClass(Type type)
    {
        this._type = type;
    }

    public List<_type> MyList { get; set; }  <----it does not like this
}
```

Comment: The easiest solution would be to make the class generic...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a generic type definition:

```
class MyClass<T>
{   
    private Type _type = typeof(string);
    public MyClass()
    {
        this._type = typeof(T);
    }

    public List<T> MyList { get; set; }  <----it likes this
}
```

If you need to accept a passed in `Type` argument and generics won't work, you can do something like:

```
class MyClass
{   
    private Type _type = typeof(string);
    public MyClass(Type type)
    {
        this._type = typeof(type);
        this.MyList = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type));
    }

    public IList MyList { get; set; }  <----it likes this
}
```

The advantage is it enforces the type constraint on the list.  Only items of the given type can be added to the list.  The downside is you need to cast every item you get from it.  It would be better if you avoided this sort of thing and used the generic example above.  A third option is to elide generics entirely:

```
class MyClass
{   
    private Type _type = typeof(string);
    public MyClass(Type type)
    {
        this._type = typeof(type);
        this.MyList = new ArrayList();
    }

    public IList MyList { get; set; }  <----it likes this
}
```

This doesn't provide any type enforcement.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: So given this how would you create a `MyClass` instance when given a `Type` object?  This is just deferring the problem.  The answer seems to assume that the OP doesn't actually need to do that.  That may or may not be true; we can't really know.

Comment: @Servy you'd do something like `MyClass<int> foo = new Myclass<int>()`, for example. Just replace `int` with whatever type you want.

Comment: @Renan That assumes you know the type at compile time.  The entire premise of the question is that you don't.  You are given a `Type` object at runtime.

Comment: It's not necessary to set `_type`. Type is available thru the `T` Generic class parameter.

Comment: @Servy I really don't understand your point. You cold build the code in the answer verbatim, and someone referencing it's assembly could use whatever type they liked - even if it's a type that's unknown in the project where this class stands. `T` is not necessarily a known type during compile time, but it will be known at runtime as you say.

Comment: @Renan If `MyClass` is generic it means that the definition of `MyClass` doesn't need to know what they type is, it could be anything, but it means that the code using `MyClass` need to know what the generic type is *at compile time* as well.  That may be the case, in fact it almost always is, but the premise of the question is that here it is not.  Perhaps even the consumer of `MyClass` doesn't know if they have ints or strings or doubles.  I understand that it's a very bad position to be in, but that is the very premise of the question.  This doesn't answer it.

Comment: I updated my answer in response to Servy's comment.  Technically, he's right.  I answered a slightly different question than the one the OP asked.

Comment: There we go, now it's a fantastic answer.

Comment: I don't have a compiler available.  It would be a shame if my beautiful and fantastic answer didn't work.  Thanks for the compliments, both.  I love SO.

Comment: Hey everyone, sorry for the delayed response.  The first suggestion worked like a charm.  I know what type I want it to be when it is created I just know it might change from time to time when I use the Class. Thank you.

Comment: @JayWalker, yeah, half of the first example could be removed.  It was oversight.

Comment: @Amy yes that is true, it was part of my incorrect way of trying to get my desired functionality.

Answer (score 6):

```
class MyClass <T>
{
    public List<T> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With generics it's easy:

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    public List<T> MyList { get; set; } 
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        MyList = new List<T>();
    }

    public List<T> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

and to use:

```
MyClass<string> x = new MyClass<string>();
x.MyList.Add("asdf");
```